# how to use setAndAllowWhileIdle in repeatetive task , because it avoids from doze mode , any example for this android

Tags: android, background, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager, android-doze

How to use `setallowWhileIdle` method for repetitive task in `AlarmManager`, because I think that is the only method that overcomes doze mode.
I need to work 24*7 task in repetitive mode, is there any example please help I am new to android

```java
 private void scheduleAlarm() {
        try{

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), KeepAliveAlarmReceiver.class);
            final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 
              KeepAliveAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
            long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();// alarm is set right away
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,firstMillis,60000, pIntent);
            System.out.println("enters into alarm manager");
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I need to do like this on setallowwhileIdle method it doesn't support repeatetive task timer.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this post by @lyc001. [Android - Repeating Alarms Allowed While Idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245022/android-repeating-alarms-allowed-while-idle)

It says

> the only Apis available in AlarmManager for
> Android 23 are setExactAndAllowWhileIdle and setAndAllowWhileIdle
> which are not for repeating alarms.

You should use either of these APIs and "reschedule the alarm every time it fires".
So, A alarm that registers another alarm, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to make your life easier!

Register for the first time (MainActivity.java)

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmRBActivity.class);

                                boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 007,
                                        intent,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

                                if(!alarmUp){

                                    long triggerTime = intent
                                            .getLongExtra("TRIGGER_TIME", System.currentTimeMillis());

                                    triggerTime += TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2);

                                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 007, intent, 0);

                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                                        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
                                    }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                                        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
                                    } else {
                                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
                                    }
                                    
                                    Log.e("alarm", "Alarm registered!");
                                }else{
                                    Log.e("alarm", "Alarm already registered!");
                                }
```

Register when triggered/ Register in loop (AlarmBRActivity.java)

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 007, AlarmIntent, 0);
            long triggerTime = intent
                    .getLongExtra("TRIGGER_TIME", System.currentTimeMillis());
            triggerTime += TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2);


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
            }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
            } else {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
            }
```

Source:
[Android AlarmManager not working on some devices when the app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739669/android-alarmmanager-not-working-on-some-devices-when-the-app-is-closed?noredirect=1&lq=1)